# ASCII stream decoding error in cl-html-parse

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I get an `ASCII stream decoding error` when I run this:

```
(with-open-file (stream file)
    (net.html.parser:parse-html stream))
```

I'm using SBCL 1.0.58 and cl-html-parse 20101006 (using quicklisp).

I get the error fairly frequently trying to parse pages I download with curl (in a regular shell). Most are UTF-8.

Should I somehow be specifying an encoding for the file, and how would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

After reading a bit more on `with-open-file`, I found I can make this work by specifying :external-format.

```
(with-open-file (stream file
                        :if-does-not-exist nil
                        :external-format :UTF-8)
    (net.html.parser:parse-html stream))
```

Still trying to figure out writing (I get a similar error), but I think I'm looking in the right place now.